# How to include html page in another page (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this page:

http://www.interload.co.il/upload/5798737.jpg

When I use the "create" page as a differrent html page it works grate, but when I include it in the main page it doesn't work.

I tried this code: (just the last row of the include matters)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>password</th>
   <th>email</th>
   <th>actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in g.companies">
   <td>{{c.id}}</td>
   <td>{{c.name}}</td>
   <td>{{c.password}}</td>
   <td>{{c.email}}</td>
   <td><button data-ng-click="g.deleteCompany($index)">X</button>
    <button name="update" ng-click="g.showUpdateCompany()">O</button></td>
   <td ng-show="g.show">
   Company id: <input value="{{c.id}}" disabled="disabled"><br/>
   Company name: <input value="{{c.name}}" disabled="disabled"><br/>
   Company password: <input ng-model="c.password"><br/>
   Company email: <input ng-model="c.email"><br/>
   <button ng-click="g.hideUpdateCompany(c)">Save</button>
   </td>
   <!--replace $index with c (the company)-->
  </tr>
 </table>
 <div ng-include src="'createCompany.html'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page I want to include:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Create new Company:</h2>
Company ID: <input type="text" ng-model="c.newCompany.id"> <br>
Company name: <input type="text" ng-model="c.newCompany.name"> <br>
Company password: <input type="password" ng-model="c.newCompany.password"> <br>
Company email: <input type="email" ng-model="c.newCompany.email"> <br>
<button ng-click="c.createCompany()">Sumbit</button> <br>
<p ng-show="c.success"> Company Added Successfully ! </p>
<p ng-show="c.failure"> Company Failed to be added ! </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**the conrollers are set in here (ui-view):**

```js
/**
 * 
 */
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ "ui.router" ]);

app.config([ '$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
} ]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $stateProvider
 .state("main", {
  url : "/main",
  templateUrl : "../HTMLs/AdminMain.html",
 })
 .state("getCompanies", {
  url : "/getCompanies",
  templateUrl : "../HTMLs/getCompanies.html",
  controller : "getCompaniesCTRL as g"
 })
 .state("createCompany", {
  url : "/createCompany",
  templateUrl : "../HTMLs/createCompany.html",
  controller : "createCompanyCTRL as c"
 })
 .state("404", {
     url : "/404",
        templateUrl : "../HTMLs/404.html"
    });
 $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/main"); // first browsing postfix is empty
           // --> route it to /main
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404'); // when no switch case matches -->
           // route to /404
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for ng-include is this:

```
<div ng-include src="updateCompany.html"></div>
```

or

```
<ng-include src="updateCompany.html"></ng-include>
```

or

```
<ng-include src="'updateCompany.html'"></ng-include>
```

or

```
<div ng-include src="'updateCompany.html'"></div>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: first of all it realy helped!
the problem now that when I use this page as a seperate page all the angular works, but when I include it to another one it dosen't.
adding new codes to the main thread.

Comment: I see that your route can't assign the controller because the route isn't appropriate.So, put the ng-controller inside the view of the html you want to include and not in the routeProvider.If this helps you vote the answer so the people know and can use the information.

Comment: yes, that exatcly what I did:
<div ng-controller="createCompanyCTRL as c" ng-app="myApp">
 <ng-include src="'createCompany.html'"></ng-include>
</div>

and it works. thank you.